# Override getJSON and get jQuery promises (done/fail)

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have to override jQuery's getJSON function and am wondering if there is a way to get promise functions (done/fail) inside the override function. I would think that the functions are stored somewhere. Here is the start of the code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.getJSON = function (url, data, callback) {
       this.done = function(){};
       this.fail = function(){};
       var newDoneFtn = function(response) {
          var newData = JSON.parse(response.data);
          //call done function here with newData variable
       }
       var newFailFtn = function() {
          //call fail function here
       }
       newFunction(url, data, newDoneFtn, newFailFtn);
    };
})(jQuery);

$.getJSON(someURL, {
   id: 1
}).done(function(data) {
   console.log(data);
}).fail(function() {
   console.log('failed');
});
```

Where I am stuck is trying to get the done and failed functions on the getJSON call to be used with the newFunction. Please note that I cannot change newFunction.

Comment: No. You just need to return a jQuery deferred.

Comment: Why do you think you need to override `getJSON`? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: I am dealing with an Android issue in Cordova and don't want to have to rewrite every getJSON function to use the cordova.plugin.http.get function for older versions of Android (before 5). Didn't mention that since I didn't want to overcomplicate things.

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to overwrite `$.ajax`, not just `$.getJSON`.

Comment: Either would work. getJSON is just a shortcut of ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new Deferred object using `$.Deferred()`.

You can then call / pass its `resolve()` and `reject()` functions to resolve or fail its promise.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I can't use promises on the newFunction and have to pass in the function variable as I have shown above.

Comment: @fanfavorite: That's what the `resolve` & `reject` methods on `Deferred` are for.  See the docs.

Comment: What if multiple getJSON calls are happening at the same time? Wouldn't the deferred object resolve all of them instead of just the one that is actually done?

Comment: @fanfavorite: You need to make a separate Deferred object for each call.

Comment: So there is no way of just doing an override then. I have to update every instance anyways?

Comment: @fanfavorite: Huh? That's what you do in your override method.  You need to understand how deferreds & promises work.

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks already answered; you can return a [$.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/):

```
function getJson(){
  var deferred = $.Deferred();
  try{
    someCallbackApi(
      param
      ,function(response){
        response.error
          ? deferred.reject(response.error)
          : deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(response.data))
      }
    );
  }catch(e){
    deferred.reject(e);
  }
  return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error that $.getJSON(...).done is not a function and even though someCallbackApi complete function gets triggered, the deferred.resolve doesn't actually call the done function. I have basically setup your code inside of what I have above. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bbrudm47/1/

Comment: Nevermind, I found that is should be return deferred.promise(). I have edited your answer. Thanks.